# Program wont exit loop after correct value is entered

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, boolean

I have a problem in this program where when I enter a correct value it gives me the correct output but it also asks me to enter my name again. It is working for when i enter an incorrect value 3 times it will terminate the program although it does not print out the error message. I am not sure how to change it so that it will only output the you are verified you may use the lift.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Username
{


public static void main (String[]args)



{   
    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    // array containing usernames 
    String [] name = {"barry", "matty", "olly","joey"}; // elements in array
    boolean x;
                x = false;
    int j = 0;
            while (j < 3)
            {


                System.out.println("Enter your name");
                String name1 = kb.nextLine();
                boolean b = true;

                for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {

                    if (name[i].equals(name1))
                    {

                        System.out.println("you are verified you may use the lift");
                        x = true;
                        break;// to stop loop checking names

                    }



                }
                if (x = false)
                {
                    System.out.println("wrong");
                }

                j++;



            }

            if(x = false)
            {
                System.out.println("Wrong password entered three times. goodbye.");

            }

}}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `if (x = false)` you are first assigning `false` to `x` which is then checked in condition. In other words your code is similar to

```
x = false;
if (x) {//...
```

You probably wanted to write

```
if (x == false) // == is used for comparisons, `=` is used for assigning
```

but don't use this style of coding. Instead you can use [Yoda conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)

```
if (false == x)// Because you can't assign new value to constant you will not 
               // make mistake `if (false = x)` <- this would not compile
```

or even better

```
if (!x)// it is the same as `if (negate(x))` which when `x` would be false would 
       // mean `if (negate(false))` which will be evaluated to `if (true)`
       // BTW there is no `negate` method in Java, but you get the idea
```

---

Form `if(x)` is equal to `if (x == true)` because

`true  == true` <==> `true`
`false == true` <==> `false`

which means

`X == true` <==> `X` (where `X` can be only true or false).

Similarly `if (!x)` means `if(x == false)`.